# Calculating DATETIME difference in Mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, duration

I am calculating time difference between the `cleartime` and `firstoccurrence` time which should result in `hh:mm:ss` format .how can i get the `Datetime DURATION` in mysql  in format `hh:mm:ss`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjNtf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `TIMEDIFF`, such as

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF("2018-01-25 13:10:11", "2018-01-24 11:10:10");
```

will output `26:00:01`

Further information on `TIMEDIFF`, please refer to the [document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

> TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2) returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a time value. expr1 and
>   expr2 are time or date-and-time expressions, but both must be of the
>   same type.

For your case, if you want to set the time duration into the column of DURATION, you can try a `UPDATE` query for all records. It would be simpler if you have an ID column, which is not shown in your screenshot.